# What is a "therapeutic agent" in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Even though English is not my native language, many phrasal nouns make sense to me. However there is this term I can't find the specific definition online.

So I come around a school guide about the nursing course:

> To be a nurse, students need to learn about the communication skills
>   needed to participate **as an effective therapeutic agent** and collaborative
>   member of the healthcare team. Students will learn the skills 
>   required to be a capable and safe registered nurse. Emotional intelligence,
>   mindfulness, and reflective practice will all be emphasised, informing quality and safety in practice and supporting self-care, professional identity formation and emergence of the professional self. Interviewing, interpersonal skill-development and multiple
>   communication platforms will be introduced.

So I try to look for the term online. But they refer to "a thing" rather than a person such as "[Exercise As A Therapeutic Agent](https://academic.oup.com/ptj/article-abstract/27/1/10/4709056?redirectedFrom=fulltext)" I think that "Therapeutic Agent" in this case means that "a nurse needs to know about "therapy" in order to grasp other people's psychology ?

Comment: I don't think "therapeutic agent" is really a phrasal noun - *therapeutic* is just a regular adjective modifying the noun *agent* here.

Answer (score 3):

It means "a good nurse".

*agent*: a person or thing that takes an active role or produces a specified effect.

*therapuetic*: relating to healing of disease

The whole quote you posted could be reduced to a few much simpler sentences, but it doesn't have much to say that isn't blindingly obvious. For example:

> A nurse needs to learn how to communicate, be
>   a good nurse, work with others, work safely, be nice
>   to others, and be able to learn new skills. Interviewing skills will also be taught.

Answer (score 1):

People can be “agents” of different types. For example, “In the end, every leader must be a **change agent**.” from [this article in Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/glennllopis/2014/03/24/every-leader-must-be-a-change-agent-or-face-extinction/#5aaeecbc4e0f).

When we describe someone as a “something agent” or an “agent of something” we usually mean that they are helping or causing that “something” to happen. In your context, students need to learn the communication skills needed to be able to be a person that is effective in helping patients to heal or improving their overall health. To put it another way, nurses should have the skills to be effective as “agents of health and healing”.

Answer (score -1):

You could parse the sentence as follows because of **and**:

> ...effective therapeutic agent [of the healthcare team] and collaborative
>   member of the healthcare team

To be an agent of the team is to represent and act on behalf of the team.

A **therapeutic agent** is jargon for one who administers therapies, which are healing treatments.

Comment: I disagree, you can't be a therapeutic agent of a healthcare  team.

Comment: It would shed more light on the matter, @Tom Church, if you explained what you think **therapeutic agent** means here rather than just registering your disagreement.